# Node.js v6.2.2 crypto.createCipheriv "Invalid key length" Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, node-crypto

Below is the source for [multipassify](https://github.com/beaucoo/multipassify/blob/master/multipassify.js).

The code works perfectly below Node 6 and gives an error onward.

The error looks like this:

```
crypto.js:184
  this._handle.initiv(cipher, toBuf(key), toBuf(iv));
               ^

Error: Invalid key length
    at Error (native)
    at new Cipheriv (crypto.js:184:16)
    at Object.Cipheriv (crypto.js:182:12)
    at multipassify.encrypt (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/super-octopus/node_modules/multipassify/multipassify.js:52:25)
    at multipassify.encode (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/super-octopus/node_modules/multipassify/multipassify.js:28:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/super-octopus/multi.js:8:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
```

Here's the source.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var BLOCK_SIZE = 16;

var multipassify = module.exports = function(secret) {
    if (!(this instanceof multipassify)) return new multipassify(secret);
    if (!(typeof secret == 'string' && secret.length > 0)) throw new Error('Invalid Secret');

    // Use the Multipass secret to derive two cryptographic keys,
    // one for encryption, one for signing
    var hash = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(secret).digest('binary');
    this._encryptionKey = hash.substring(0, BLOCK_SIZE);
    this._signingKey = hash.substring(BLOCK_SIZE, 32);
    return this;
};

multipassify.prototype.encode = function(obj) {
    if (!obj) return;

    // Store the current time in ISO8601 format.
    // The token will only be valid for a small timeframe around this timestamp.
    obj["created_at"] = new Date().toISOString();

    // Serialize the customer data to JSON and encrypt it
    var cipherText = this.encrypt(JSON.stringify(obj));

    // Create a signature (message authentication code) of the ciphertext
    // and encode everything using URL-safe Base64 (RFC 4648)
    var token = new Buffer(cipherText + this.sign(cipherText),'binary').toString('base64');
    token = token.replace(/\+/g, '-') // Replace + with -
        .replace(/\//g, '_'); // Replace / with _

    return token;
};

multipassify.prototype.generateUrl = function(obj, domain) {
    if(!domain) return;
    return "https://" + domain + "/account/login/multipass/" + this.encode(obj);
};

multipassify.prototype.sign = function (data) {
    var signed = crypto.createHmac("SHA256", this._signingKey).update(data).digest('binary');
    return signed;
}

multipassify.prototype.encrypt = function(plaintext) {
    // Use a random IV
    var iv = crypto.randomBytes(BLOCK_SIZE);
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', this._encryptionKey,iv);

    // Use IV as first block of ciphertext
    var encrypted = iv.toString('binary') + cipher.update(plaintext, 'utf8', 'binary') + cipher.final('binary');
    return encrypted;
}
```

I've tried messing around with converting the hash and `this._encryptionKey` to binary. Using this [github issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6696) as a guide but I'm having no luck trying to get this working with Node 6. Anyone know an easy way to get this working with later versions of node?

Comment: Have you printed the key and iv length just prior to being used?

Comment: @zaph the lengths for `iv` and `this._encryptionKey` are `16`.

Answer (score 1):

Came across the fix in a fork of the repo.

https://github.com/achinn/multipassify/blob/176c7664c8458cdfb8f20fac97fe27b7b7d1bff4/multipassify.js

All of the "binary" statements are removed because I believe it's the default, so no sense in switching back and forth.

I also noticed that `Buffer.concat([value, value])` is being used over `new Buffer(value + value)`.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var BLOCK_SIZE = 16;

var multipassify = module.exports = function(secret) {
    if (!(this instanceof multipassify)) return new multipassify(secret);
    if (!(typeof secret == 'string' && secret.length > 0)) throw new Error('Invalid Secret');

    // Use the Multipass secret to derive two cryptographic keys,
    // one for encryption, one for signing
    var hash = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(secret).digest();
    this._encryptionKey = hash.slice(0, BLOCK_SIZE);
    this._signingKey = hash.slice(BLOCK_SIZE, 32);
    return this;
};

multipassify.prototype.encode = function(obj) {
    if (!obj) return;

    // Store the current time in ISO8601 format.
    // The token will only be valid for a small timeframe around this timestamp.
    obj["created_at"] = new Date().toISOString();

    // Serialize the customer data to JSON and encrypt it
    var cipherText = this.encrypt(JSON.stringify(obj));

    // Create a signature (message authentication code) of the ciphertext
    // and encode everything using URL-safe Base64 (RFC 4648)
    var token = Buffer.concat([cipherText, this.sign(cipherText)]).toString('base64');
    token = token.replace(/\+/g, '-') // Replace + with -
        .replace(/\//g, '_'); // Replace / with _

    return token;
};

multipassify.prototype.generateUrl = function(obj, domain) {
    if(!domain) return;
    return "https://" + domain + "/account/login/multipass/" + this.encode(obj);
};

multipassify.prototype.sign = function (data) {
    var signed = crypto.createHmac("SHA256", this._signingKey).update(data).digest();
    return signed;
}

multipassify.prototype.encrypt = function(plaintext) {
    // Use a random IV
    var iv = crypto.randomBytes(BLOCK_SIZE);
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', this._encryptionKey,iv);

    // Use IV as first block of ciphertext
    var encrypted = Buffer.concat([iv, cipher.update(plaintext, 'utf8'), cipher.final()]);
    return encrypted;
}
```